# Appium Studio's Reflection Screen is displaying black screen even when successfully connected to Bluestack emulator

Tags: android, appium-android, bluestacks

I am running Appium Studio with Bluestack (Android v7.1).

After connecting to Bluestack, the reflection screen on Android device of Appium Studio is showing black screen.

When I open an app in Bluestack, the app is not displayed in Bluestack. Bluestack only shows the background display. Over at the reflection, it is still black screen. However, when I click on screen orientation at the reflection screen, the Bluestack’s orientation is affected, which indicates there’s connection between Appium Studio and Bluestack. Another indication of success is when I click Home button of the reflection screen, Bluestack can display Home screen.

Hope to have advice on this. Thank you.

The following is a [video shot](https://youtu.be/Y5uUJNzH90o) of what happened and also a [link](https://razermis-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/chiomeng_lam_razer_com/EbDsxM0XsllPhRh8o7CqGxMBVxp_laifYgaUr9E5vvM2ZQ?e=JrGgKs) to the appium log for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of program you are using is restricted and doesn't allow recording. You can solve this problem by using LSPAtch and Disable-Flag_Secure. By downloading these tools you can configure program and easily inspect the parts you want.